# mapStateToProps accessing different indexes of an array

Tags: javascript, indexing, mapstatetoprops

I'm trying to access different indexes of an array to display in one of my components, but I'm having trouble. This is the code I'm using at the moment:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        weight: state.move[0].movementWeight,
        name: state.move[0].movementName
    }
};
```

Here is the code for the button the user clicks which determines what index is needed:

```
const MovementButton = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const mapNames = props.name.map((lift) => {
        return (
            <Button 
                key={lift.movementName}
                className={classes.movementButtons} 
                onClick={() => history.push(`/movement/${lift.movementName}/${lift.movementWeight}`)}
            >
                {lift.movementName} - {lift.movementWeight}lbs
            </Button>
        )
    });
    const displayMovementButtons = () => {
        if (mapNames.length === 0) {    
            return <div className={classes.noMovementsMessage} >Click add button to begin</div> 
        };

        return <div>{mapNames}</div>
    };

    return <div className={classes.movementButtonsDiv}>{displayMovementButtons()}</div>
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        name: state.move
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MovementButton);
```

But this makes props.weight always how the 0 index, whereas sometimes I need index 1, 2, etc. The reason I'm using the [0] is because without it, I get undefined.
Any help?

Comment: How do you determine when you need index 1, 2 etc?

Comment: `state.move` is an array so `movementWeight` is not a property of it, hence you get `undefined`.

Comment: @FullstackGuy I updated the code to show the button the user clicks on. Each button has a different name/weight on it. Depending on which one is clicked, the page that is rendered should show the corresponding name/weight.